# How to get the value on a string between 2 identifiers, without replacing the identifiers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string:

```
<a href="#" title="blahblah?foo=1&month={m{month}m}">bar</a>
```

So I can pull the title as a string, but I want to replace the {m{month}m} with {m{August}m} and it needs to be flexible enough so I can also then again replace it with {m{September}m}

I currently have this:

```
var thetitle = $(this).attr('title');
var newtitle = thetitle.replace("{m{month}m}",months[currentmonth]);
```

And this replaces fine the 1st time, but then it strips out the entire value and replaces "{m{month}m}" with say "August", so when I need to replace it again I can't target it.

Any help would be appreciated.

G

Comment: `yourstring.substring(3, yourstring.length - 3)` should give you the `month`, `april`, `septemper` or whatever. use that and replace with the needed month name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
var changeMonth = (function(){
    var previous = 'month'  ; 

   return function(title,month){
      var temp = previous;
      previous = month
      return title.replace('m{' + temp + '}m', month);
   }
})();
```

This works for me. Try

```js
var changeMonth = (function(){
    var previous = 'month'  ; 

   return function(title,month){
      var temp = previous;
      previous = month;
      return title.replace('m{' + temp + '}m','m{'+  month + '}m');
   }
})();

var input = $('input');
var a = $('a');

$('button').on('click', function(){
  var month = input.val();
  var newMonth = changeMonth($(a).attr('title'), month);
  $(a).attr('title', newMonth);
  console.log($(a).attr('title'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="blahblah?foo=1&month={m{month}m}"></a>
Your month here<input type='text'>
<button>Change</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = "blahblah?foo=1&month={m{August}m}";

var previousmonth = "August";
var previousmonthstr = "{m{" + previousmonth + "}m}";

var currentmonth = "September";
var currentmonthstr = "{m{" + currentmonth + "}m}";

var newtitle = title.replace(previousmonthstr, currentmonthstr);

// Your title is stored in newtitle
```

View live demo [here](http://jsbin.com/hucaxa/edit?js,console)